# How to delay the visibility of a Loader element content in qml?

Tags: qt, qml, loader

I'm using a Loader element to load the main content qml in a asynchronous way and have it ready while showing another qml actively on the window.

I'm trying to show the loader_two content on a timer expiry of 2 seconds. But the loader_two is visible as soon as it is loaded even before the timer expiry. How do I achieve this?

Here is my code.

```
    Loader{
    id:loader_one
    active: true
    visible: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    asynchronous: true
    source: "Start.qml"
    onLoaded: {
        loader_two.active = true
        show_content_timer.start()
    }
}

Loader{
    id:loader_two
    active:false
    anchors.fill: parent
    asynchronous: true
    source: "Main_content.qml"
}
Timer{
    id: show_content_timer
    interval: 2000
    repeat: false
    running: false
    triggeredOnStart: false
    onTriggered:
    {
        console.log("2seconds expired")
        loader_one.source = ""
        loader_one.item.visible = false;
        loader_two.item.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You set `loader_two.active = true` in `loader_one.onLoaded` without delay.

Comment: I'm setting it because I need the loader two's content to be ready in the background. If the Loader is inactive, changing the source will not cause the item to be instantiated until the Loader is made active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to achieve the delay by setting the loader_two's visibility to false by default and setting it to true once my timer expires. I was trying the same by controlling the loader_two.item.visible property which didn't work earlier.

Here is my final working code. Thanks.

```
Loader{
id:loader_one
active: true
visible: true
anchors.fill: parent
asynchronous: true
source: "Start.qml"
onLoaded: {
    loader_two.active = true
    show_content_timer.start()
}
}

Loader{
id:loader_two
active:false
visible: false
anchors.fill: parent
asynchronous: true
source: "Main_content.qml"
}
Timer{
id: show_content_timer
interval: 2000
repeat: false
running: false
triggeredOnStart: false
onTriggered:
{
    console.log("2seconds expired")
    loader_one.source = ""
    loader_one.item.visible = false;
    loader_two.visible = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Component and  then do Component.create() in order to create an Item that will load remotely, but will not display until you call Component.create()

```
Loader {

    id: loader_one
    active: true
    visible: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    asynchronous: true
    source: "Start.qml"
    onLoaded: {
        loader_two.active = true
        show_content_timer.start();
    }
}

Component {
    id: loaderComponent 


    Loader{
        id:loader_two
        active:false
        anchors.fill: parent
        asynchronous: true
        source: "Main_content.qml";
    }

}

Timer {
    id: show_content_timer
    interval: 2000
    repeat: false
    running: false
    triggeredOnStart: false
    onTriggered:
    {
        console.log("2seconds expired")
        loaderComponent.create();
    }
```

Comment: But doesn't using a component instantiates the content immediately? which will affect the startup time.

Comment: You could always use  C++ to accomplish your goal with QTimer::singleShot  and QQmlComponent::create()  if you wanted it to be instantiated dynamically